# Change iframe size without making iframe content move

Tags: html, css, iframe

As title.  I am developing a GIS system.  I have a page with 2 iframes that each of them shows a map, and these 2 iframes split my screen to 50%/50% at the beginning (my case is one at left side,the other at right side),  and users can change the size of these iframes by dragging the split line between 2 frames.  BUT when size of the iframes change, the map inside these iframes are moving.  How could I change the size of iframe without making the maps in iframes move?

Comment: Give fixed width to your maps

Comment: Also, it will be better if you can post runnable snippet of your code so that others can understand better and give a better solution

Comment: https://codepen.io/MikiHoshitsuki437SH/pen/YzPVbvq     As the button is being dragged horizontally, the text is moving, but is it possible to make the text don't move?